# Remove markup from render pagecontent

Tags: views, theming

I am theming a page in D7 and need to change the markup that gets rendered out when I print`<?php print render($page['content']); ?>`. Currently it prints `<div class="">...some content</div>`, where I want it to print `<section>some content...</section>`
I only want to do this on this page and not globally to others. Is there another call or variable I can add to manipulate the markup?

Comment: Well. I kind of found a cheat for this. In my case, I was using a view for the page, so I used the views embed view feature https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7 and that worked. Not the best, but it worked. I will continue to dig into the above and post if I find anything for others looking to do the same.

Comment: Since you needed it only for one view, using that function rather than 'theming' sounds like the best solution.